# Print in JSTL by using foreach hours values

Tags: java, foreach, jstl

I would like to print by using JSTL a list of hours values. I have though to use foreach in this way

```
<select>
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="23" var="hour">
         <option value="${hour}">${hour}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But I get values like `0 1 2`, instead I would like to get values like `00 01 02 03` and so on.Does it exist a way to achieve this by using foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `formatNumber` core tag and its `minIntegerDigits` attribute like so:

```
<select>
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="23" var="hour">
         <option value="${hour}">
             <fmt:formatNumber value="${hour}" type="number" minIntegerDigits="2"/>
         </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```